# Jenkins Agent Node - what data from Jenkins does it store?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I would like to know what data does the Jenkins Agent node stores?
When I add node in Jenkins, we need to specify the "remote root directory".
Does any logs, job runs or artifacts get stored on the agent node?

I tried to run a sample pipeline script from Jenkins however I did not see anything being logged or stored on the Jenkins agent node, however I am seeing the artifacts and job runs folder on the controller.
May I know if by default the agent node does not store anything?
If I would like to store job runs or artifacts on the Agent node, where should I configure it?